# Save image over existing image

Tags: c#, image, jpeg

I am working on a C# application wherein the first thing I want to do is to rotate images based upon the metadata in the file.  This part works just fine.  But saving the image over top of the existing image is where I'm having trouble.  I delete the original file, close the stream and try to save the image as the name of the original image but it's not working. I get the following exception:

```
'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dllAdditional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
```

This is the code I'm using.  Its a little different than what my working version was so forgive me if I missed something.  In my original version I just saved the

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(item, FileMode.Open)) {
    im = Image.FromStream(fs);
    sourceFormat = im.RawFormat;

    // Get the image orientation from the image metadata 
    PropertyItem pi = im.GetPropertyItem(274);
    int orientation = pi.Value[0];

    switch (orientation) {
        // TODO: Set rotation and flips for all orientations
        // case 1 - 5 & 7 removed for clarity
        //    break;
        case 6:
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Transformation, (long)EncoderValue.TransformRotate90);
            edited = true;
            pi.Value[0] = 1;
            im.SetPropertyItem(pi);
            fs.Close();
            File.Delete(item);
            im.Save(item, GetEncoder(sourceFormat), encoderParameters);
            break;
        case 8:
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Transformation, (long)EncoderValue.TransformRotate270);
            pi.Value[0] = 1;
            im.SetPropertyItem(pi);
            fs.Close();
            File.Delete(item);
            im.Save(item, GetEncoder(sourceFormat), encoderParameters);
            break;
        } 
    }

    im.Dispose();
    if (encoderParameters != null)
        encoderParameters.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you save the image under a different filename?

Comment: not in this configuration but it does if I do all my saving and deleting after the using filestream.  So what I originally had to make it work was a bool that if the image was edited then we would do the saving and deleting after the using block.  And in that instance I had to use a different name - appended a -1 to the end of the filename.

Comment: Does this help http://alperguc.blogspot.in/2008/11/c-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi.html

Comment: Where exactly does the exception occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code to test [this](http://alperguc.blogspot.in/2008/11/c-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi.html) solution (proof only, not reworking your implementation)

```
encoderParameters.Param[0] = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Transformation, (long)System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderValue.TransformRotate90);
//edited = true;
pi.Value[0] = 1;
im.SetPropertyItem(pi);

// Added new memorystream
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
// Read into memorystream
im.Save(ms, GetEncoder(sourceFormat), encoderParameters);
fs.Close();
File.Delete(item);

// Read from memorystream into byte array
byte[] ni = ms.ToArray();
// Save out using new filestream.
using (FileStream nfs = new FileStream(item, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)){
    nfs.Write(ni, 0, ni.Length);
}
//im.Save(item, GetEncoder(sourceFormat), encoderParameters);
```

Comment: Yep this does the trick.  I started going through the solution that was noted in the comments and then just saw this.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the filestream to ReadWrite. Also, try not to `Dispoose`. I believe that is your main problem. Also, do not close `fs` till you are finished with it. I suggest you close `fs` and the image *after* you are done using it. Maybe at the end of the function.